# IntelliJ multi module test coverage

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.2 (Ultimate Edition) for multiple services using Gradle and Spock testing.  I can currently run each module test coverage just fine.  But when I run one module/service, it removes the coverage for the previous testing.

Here is what I am trying:

- Select each module in the Project view
- Right click and select "Run Test.. with Coverage"
- this creates a "whole project" configuration
- When I try to run that configuration with coverage, I get the error:
  [image]

I did try to use the modify options, but I noticed that the "whole project" configuration is in the JUnit section, even though I am using Gradle / Groovy /Spock.  Here is a requested screenshot of the "Run Configuration":

[image]

I feel like there has to be a way to show a collective code coverage for the selected modules but so far my research hasn't helped.

Comment: Hello, can you please provide the screenshot with configuration that describes the following: I did try to use the modify options, but I noticed that the "whole project" configuration is in the JUnit section, even though I am using Gradle / Groovy. Thanks

Comment: I updated the OP with the screen shot.

Comment: Do I get it right that you want to run the test (with coverage) with Gradle, not with Junit runner? If yes, please check the following settings: Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle

Comment: What I have been doing is going to each module, right clicking the src/test/grooy folder and selecting "More Run/Debug | run tests...code coverage"  But I have to do this on a per module basis which only gathers that modules coverage.  
I think I need to run these coverage tests from within IntelliJ to show the coverage there?

Comment: we've created an issue for investigating, you can follow it here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-296626